# Accessing Activities:List from the GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'm implementing the Google Play services in an attempt to build a cross network aggregator for android. Although not ideal, the functionality provided in the HTTP API [to get a list of activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities) will do an acceptable job. However, I can't seem to find any of this functionality provided by the GoogleApiClient.

I guess my main question is: Does it exist, if not, can you make REST calls from the [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) without dealing with OAuth2?

Comment: Hello @DVDCXN I am having same problem like you..So I want to know..Have you got your answer or is it possible?

Comment: Same here. Can't access activities from GoogleApiClient for any users. Did you find smth ?

Comment: I managed to create a rather inelegant and half featured solution that can achieve a semblance of a newsfeed. Unfortunately only public posts are available, and only those of visible friends.  

First, I used the google+ SDK to query for a list of visible people as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people).  

Next I iterated through each returned person, using their id number to query the [HTTP API People](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list).

As I said, the solution is undesirable but until google actually open up their API nothing can be done

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to perform activities.list API calls without a user-authorized client. You must, however, authorize your client with a developer API key from [the Google developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

When you make an API call to activities.list, make sure to pass a valid Google+ ID to the API call, the special value "me" requires the user to authorize your app. Also, for aggregation, you may want to consider the activities.search API.

Comment: I can't find any instructions or information of how to make the call using the play services API. I've checked the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/package-summary.html) but I'm stumped

Comment: I'll see what I put together in terms of a simple example; from Android, you typically use the Java client library for Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the calls you're looking for are under their older name of "Moments" (see https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus.html#MomentsApi )